# How to change border of individual mat-cell?

Tags: html, css, angular, mat-table

I have an Angular app with the following table:

```
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;" >
    <ng-container matColumnDef="network">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Network</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <span class="truncate-text">{{row.network}}</span>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="config">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [ngClass]="'shortWidth'">Config</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [ngClass]="'shortWidth'">
        <span class="truncate-text">{{row.config}}</span>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="value">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Value</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <span class="truncate-text">{{row.value}}</span>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; let i=index; columns: displayedColumns;" style="min-height: 34px;">
    </mat-row>
  </mat-table>
```

I would like to remove the border between rows for the first mat-cell "network".
I've tried various things for example:

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [ngStyle]="{'border': 'none'}">
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [ngStyle]="{'border': '0'}">
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [ngStyle]="{'border-bottom-width': '0'}">
```

And all sorts for things but none work. It seems that the styling of mat-row which includes a border between rows can't be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

the border on material table is showing for data row. if you don't want to show the border you need to add this **[ngStyle]="{'border': 'none'}"** on row. after hiding border from row, you can now add border to individual cells.

your code will looks like this

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;" >
    <ng-container matColumnDef="network">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Network</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <span class="truncate-text">{{row.network}}</span>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="config">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [ngClass]="'shortWidth'">Config</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell [ngStyle]="{'border-top': '1px solid black'}" *matCellDef="let row" [ngClass]="'shortWidth'">
        <span class="truncate-text">{{row.config}}</span>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="value">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Value</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell [ngStyle]="{'border-top': '1px solid black'}" *matCellDef="let row">
        <span class="truncate-text">{{row.value}}</span>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row [ngStyle]="{'border': 'none'}" *matRowDef="let row; let i=index; columns: displayedColumns;" style="min-height: 34px;">
    </mat-row>
  </mat-table>
```

[click to view demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-table-border-style)